# The first column of imported .CSV cannot be referenced by its label

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am importing a simple .CSV with column labels using `np.genfromtxt(names=True)`. In the Spyder variable explorer, I can see that the `ndarray` is created containing the two columns of data with the correct labels `x` and `y`, however, whenever I try to print a column of the array using its label, only the second column can be printed. The first column produces `ValueError: no field of name x`. I've tried changing the column names without success and can't make sense why the second column prints and the first one does not.

test.csv contents:

```
x,y
1,2
2,4
3,6
4,8
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_path = 'test.csv'

data = np.genfromtxt(data_path, delimiter=',', names=True)

print(data['y']) #prints fine
print(data['x']) #produces error but is visible in the correct record array field
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into Spyder and couldn't reproduce the error - the data prints fine for me.

Comment: Could not reproduce - your code works fine for me. btw this feels like something where `pandas` is better to use rather than `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you, seems like something is getting messed up in the original .CSV. It was created in Excel, when I made the same data in a text document it works fine too.